# How do I mock AddAsync?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, moq, xunit

I'm writing unit test. For testing the method below,

```
public async Task<Guid> CreateWebJobStatus(string blobId, Guid loggedInUserId, string loggedInUserEmail) {

    Guid webJobStatusId = Guid.NewGuid();

    WebJobStatus newWebJobStatus = new WebJobStatus
    {
        WorkJobStatusId = webJobStatusId,
        TransactionId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Status = (int)WebJobStatusEnum.PENDING,
        BlobId = blobId,
        UserId = loggedInUserId,
        UserEmail = loggedInUserEmail,
    };
    await _dbContext.WebJobStatus.AddAsync(newWebJobStatus);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return webJobStatusId;
}
```

I mocked dbset and dbcontext

```
public async void CreateWebJobStatusTest() {
    var dbOption = new DbContextOptions<TimeSeriesDbContext>();
    var mockDbContext = new Mock<TimeSeriesDbContext>(dbOption);
    var mockConfig = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
    var instance = new WebJobStatusRepository(mockConfig.Object, mockDbContext.Object);
    var mockValidWebJobId = "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111";
    var webjobStatusList = new List<WebJobStatus>() {
        new WebJobStatus {
            WorkJobStatusId = Guid.Parse(mockValidWebJobId),
            GroupName = "testGroupName",
            Status = 3,
            CreatedDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-10)
        }
    };
    var mockWebJobDbSet = UnitTestUtil.CreateDbSetMock<WebJobStatus>(webjobStatusList.AsQueryable());
    mockDbContext.Setup(x => x.WebJobStatus).Returns(mockWebJobDbSet.Object);

    mockWebJobDbSet.Setup(x => x.AddAsync(It.IsAny<WebJobStatus>(), It.IsAny<System.Threading.CancellationToken>())).Callback((WebJobStatus wj) =>{webjobstatusList.add(wj);});


    var mockuserId = Guid.Parse("22222222-1111-1111-1111-111111111111");

    var result = await instance.CreateWebJobStatus("testBlobId.tsv", mockuserId, "testEmail");
    Assert.IsType<Guid>(result);
    mockDbContext.Verify(x => x.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<System.Threading.CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
    mockWebJobDbSet.Verify(x => x.AddAsync(It.IsAny<WebJobStatus>(), It.IsAny<System.Threading.CancellationToken>()), Times.Once);
}
```

everything works as expect except the `AddAsync`, the exception is

> Invalid callback. Setup on method with parameters (WebJobStatus,CancellationToken) cannot invoke callback with parameters (WebJobStatus).

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: If I changed AddAsync to just Add, the test passed perfectly, but we dont change the code due to we don't know how to mock it, right...?

Comment: I would use the InMemory Provider of the ef core instead of mocking the existing functionality. Have a look at this post: [Testing with InMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory). Hope this might help. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need to return a Task to allow the async/await call

```
await _dbContext.WebJobStatus.AddAsync(newWebJobStatus);
```

to flow to completion.

So assuming that Add returns the object added

```
mockWebJobDbSet
    .Setup(_ => _.AddAsync(It.IsAny<WebJobStatus>(), It.IsAny<System.Threading.CancellationToken>()))
    .Callback((WebJobStatus model, CancellationToken token) => { webjobstatusList.Add(model); })
    .Returns((WebJobStatus model, CancellationToken token) => Task.FromResult((EntityEntry<WebJobStatus>)null));
```

Note that the method being `Setup` takes two arguments, so the `Callback` and `Returns` will need to expect two arguments as well if they want to use the captured arguments.

Comment: I am not an expert in MOQ, but after reading documentation could the final line be simplified to 
.ReturnsAsync((WebJobStatus model, CancellationToken token) => null);

Answer (score 2):

In .net core 3.1, I had to rewrite the `Returns` as below:

```
.Returns((T model, CancellationToken token) => new ValueTask<EntityEntry<T>>());
```

Answer (score 2):

Not pretty, but this was the only way I found to mock AddAsync and make it return an actual value:

```
mockWebJobDbSet
.Setup(_ => _.AddAsync(It.IsAny<WebJobStatus>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
.Callback((WebJobStatus model, CancellationToken token) => { webjobStatusList.Add(model); })
.Returns((WebJobStatus model, CancellationToken token) => ValueTask.FromResult(new EntityEntry<WebJobStatus>
(new InternalEntityEntry(
    new Mock<IStateManager>().Object,
    new RuntimeEntityType("WebJobStatus", typeof(WebJobStatus), false, null, null, null, ChangeTrackingStrategy.Snapshot, null, false),
    model)
)));
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I have done mocking is the following:-

```cs
var myList = new List<MyClass>();
       
_dataContext.Setup(m => m.MyClasses.AddAsync(It.IsAny<MyClass>(), default))
            .Callback<Slide, CancellationToken>((s, token) => {myList.Add(s);});
        
_dataContext.Setup(c => c.SaveChangesAsync(default))
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(1))
            .Verifiable();
```

And the actual implementation is the following:-

```cs
public async Task<int> AddMyClassAsync(MyClass myClass)
{
    await _careMapsDataContext.MyClasses.AddAsync(myClass);
        
    return await _careMapsDataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```