# How do I mock AddAsync in dotnet core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq, xunit

This is my code for setup.

```
this.dbSetMock
    .Setup(x => x.AddAsync(It.IsAny<BaseEntity>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))                 
    .Callback((BaseEntity model, CancellationToken token) => { testObjectList.Add(model); })
    .Returns((BaseEntity entity, CancellationToken token) => new ValueTask<BaseEntity>(Task.FromResult((EntityEntry<BaseEntity>)null));
```

But I get compile time error for conversion

[image: Compile time error for conversion]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I mock AddAsync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49142556/how-do-i-mock-addasync)

Comment: The member being mocked is suppose to return a `Task` but you are trying to return a `ValueTask` The two types are not directly related (inheritance). `ValueTask` wraps a `Task`

Comment: Show the subject under test and what it is you are actually trying to do

Comment: Can you please give me the piece of code for creating a unit test with dot net core 3.1 with maq DB context?

Comment: **Do not mock DbContext** - use In-Memory provider instead.